# save tableview data in swift MVC (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model-view-controller

How save tableview data in swift MVC?

How can i save data in table on another ViewController?

I have a custom class called ToDoItem.

```
func save() {
    let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: ToDoItem.self)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "todosave")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
//
func load() {
    if let decoded = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "todosave") {
        let _ = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded as! Data) as! [ToDoItem]
    }
}
```

I've tried saving it with NSUserDefaults but I get an error.

**ToDoItem.swift**

```
import Foundation

class ToDoItem: NSObject, NSCoding {

  var id: String
  var image: String
  var title: String
  var date: Date
   init(id: String, image: String, title: String, date: Date) {
     self.id = id
     self.image = image
     self.title = title
     self.date = date
   }

   required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     let id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as! String
     let image = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "image") as! String
     let title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
     let date = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "date") as! Date
     self.init(id: id, image: image, title: title, date: date)
   }

   func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
     aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
     aCoder.encode(image, forKey: "image")
     aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
     aCoder.encode(date, forKey: "date")
  }
}
```

Comment: You question is misleading. Please clarify it

Comment: what error. do you got?

Comment: @Sergiob How can i save this date in UserDefaults?

Comment: @Lenin App crash on startup

Comment: UserDefaults have methods to save dates

Comment: 1. You don't pass an actual instance to the save method, 2. you set a type for a class "ToDoItem" and you want to cast it to an array "[ToDoItem]"

Comment: https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/using-nskeyedarchiver-to-persist-data-976ab2f28006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Object Mapper and then you can convert the object to JSON, after convert you save it to User Defaults as normally with type Any. Then for loading data, you map the data from the User Defaults key that you saved before to your TODOItem.

The link for ObjectMapper: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper
Also you can use this library for mapping different JSONs to your desired objects